# Crystal Report: Data in header fields not same as data further down page

Tags: grouping, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I'm writing a crystal report that needs to display data, in groups, with a header at the top of the page denoting what groups am looking at. The header needs to appear on every page. When I put the group name fields in the detail section, they show the correct grouping titles, but they do not persist when I scroll through the pages. When I put the group name fields in the header section of the report, they are correct for the first group of data but when I scroll through to the next group of data, the group name fields don't update until the second page of data in the new group. I'm at my wits end with the thing. I do not know much about crystal reports and I haven't been able to find any information even slightly pertaining to the issue I am seeing. Any advice would be appreciated.
Cheers
DrJaul

EDIT:Thanks for the suggestion, Amagii! The  header fields in the Group header section still disappear if there is enough data to take up multiple pages and the header fields in the page header section still update as though they are one page behind. Though this did keep the header fields in the Page header section from getting more than one group behind. If i can just figure out  how to get data fields in the page header section to  represent the data on the current page, ill be golden.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Disclaimer: I know nothing at all about Crystal Reports. However, I've been around Stack Overflow a bit and I have a couple of suggestions: a) Find a better tag for your question than "groupname". There seem to be several, version-specific, Crystal Reports tags; if you choose the right one, it's likely that an expert will find your question and provide you a useful answer quite quickly.

Comment: b) Don't just say "I've tried everything I can thnk of". Do say I've tried "This". "This", "This" and "This" and this is what happened. I often find that just by going through this exercise I think of something else to try and/or work out what my problem was. (On the ocasions when it doesn't, it prevents someone from asking - they always will :-)). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your grouping, look for a setting to have it start a new page per group.  That way it will start a new page with a new GROUP HEADER that you can have list off all the pertinent information.